# Why do these two NHibernate queries produce different results?

Tags: nhibernate, criteria, linq-to-nhibernate

This is for a M:N relationship, with the collection being mapped in NHibernate as a Set.

The criteria query we were using previously "worked" but it did not populate the Skills collection properly, in that only the first/looking-for skill was brought down, even if the employee had multiple skills.

I changed it to a LINQ query and it fixes the issue, properly fetching all the skills of that employee.

```vb
Dim sId = 1 ' Just to have one for example
Dim lstEmployees = Session.CreateCriteria(Of Employee)() _
                    .CreateAlias("Skills", "s", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin) _
                    .Add(Expression.Or(Expression.Eq("PrimarySkillId", sId),
                                       Expression.Eq("s.Id", sId))) _
                    .SetResultTransformer(New DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer()) _
                    .List(Of Employee)()

' Returns correct employees but only their first skill in the Skills collection, even if they have more than one

Dim lstEmployees = (From e In Session.Query(Of Employee)()
                  Where e.PrimarySkillId =sId OrElse e.Skills.Any(Function(s) s.Id = sId)
                  Select e Distinct).Fetch(Function(e) e.Skills).ToList()

' Returns correct employees and their Skills collection contains all of their skills
```

Does anyone understand what's different about the two seemingly-equivalent queries?

Comment: Have you compared the SQL queries generated by both? That should give you a hint as to what the issue is.

Comment: Yes, but I wasn't sure *why* it was different when it appeared to look the same to me in code. The second query uses an `EXISTS` statement subquery which the first did not do at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the bat, the first query is doing the distinct separation after retrieving all rows, while the second query actually does a `select distinct ...`. What's likely happening is that it hydrates the Employee model with just the one Skill retrieved

To make the first query actually do a `select distinct ...` you will need to use projections.

Something like

```vb
Session.CreateCriteria(Of Employee)() _
       .CreateAlias("Skills", "s", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
       .Add(Expression.Or(Expression.Eq("PrimarySkillId", sId),
                          Expression.Eq("s.Id", sId))) _
       .SetProjection(Projections.Distinct("Id")) _
       .SetFetchMode("s", FetchMode.Eager)
```

may work. Alternatively you can try to just set the fetch mode with the DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer

```vb
Session.CreateCriteria(Of Employee)() _
       .CreateAlias("Skills", "s", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
       .Add(Expression.Or(Expression.Eq("PrimarySkillId", sId),
                          Expression.Eq("s.Id", sId))) _
       .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer) _
       .SetFetchMode("s", FetchMode.Eager)
```

Comment: I'll see if that works; I had tried the `SetFetchMode` but I did it before `CreateAlias` and I did `SetFetchMode("Skills", FetchMode.Eager)`. It didn't seem to work, so maybe it matters that it comes last or is using the alias "s"?

Comment: Thanks Vadim, I tried both ways and neither work. For the first one, it seems to only select the Id property and can't convert it to a list of Employees. For the second, it is still the same query with the same results. I'm wondering, according to LINQ, it's an EXISTS subquery. Maybe a detached criteria would work? I don't know how to do that very well, though.

Comment: @subkamran, that was going to be my next suggestion, but those are a little more complicated.

Comment: The LINQ works fine, which I'm OK with, but `FetchMany` is broken in NH3.1 and VB.NET. I'd like to fetch some grandchild records but I can't until they fix it so that is why I am interested in getting this to work in Criteria.